# The cookie was removed when I reflesh the page

Tags: express, cookies, next.js

I am building full stack app using next js and node.js + exppress.js. When user Login the website  backend send to token with cookie and cookie was set to browser. But I dont access to cookie by the next js middleware.I dont know what is  incorrect in my code.However The cookie was removed when I reflesh the page....

```
export const LoginUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        email,
      },
    });
    if (user) {
      if (user.password == password) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ name: user.id }, `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`, {
          expiresIn: "1d",
        });

        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        });`your text`
        res.status(200).json({
          user,
          token,
          succeded: true,
          message: "Login Succesfully",
        });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({
        succeded: false,
        message: "There is no such user",
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      succeded: false,
      message: "Oh no, There is a Problem...",
      error,
    });
  }
};
```

//RTK QUERY REQUEST

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "userApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080",
    credentials: "include",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query<IUser[], void>({
      query: () => `users`,
    }),
    getUser: builder.mutation<any, any>({
      query: (user) => ({
        url: "/users/login",
        method: "POST",
        body: user,
      }),
    }),
    registerUser: builder.mutation<any, any>({
      query: (user) => ({
        url: "/users/register",
        method: "POST",
        body: user,
      }),
    }),
    registerMatchResult: builder.mutation<
      IUser[],
      { idOne: string; idTwo: string }
    >({
      query: ({ idOne, idTwo }) => ({
        url: "/game-register",
        method: "POST",
        body: { idOne, idTwo },
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

//Next.js middleware --

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  // get cookie token
  const hasToken = req.cookies.get("jwt");
  console.log(hasToken);
  console.log(req.url);

  // protected routes (admin routes)
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard")) {
    if (hasToken) {
      return NextResponse.next();
    } else {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", req.url));
    }
  }

  // login & register routes
  if (["/login", "/register"].includes(req.nextUrl.pathname)) {
    if (hasToken) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", req.url));
    } else {
      return NextResponse.next();
    }
  }
}
```

//and cookie

[image: the cookie]